# cannot see files after mounting encfs directory

Tags: linux, encryption, encfs

I have an ubuntu 18.04 machine with encrypted home partition and the home directory is backed up using rsnapshot. So for example, I have the following directory structure in my rsnapshot drive:

```
darren@hepburn ~ $ ls -al /mnt/snapshots/hourly.0/hepburn/home/.ecryptfs/darren/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   4 darren darren  4096 Apr  7 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root    4096 Nov 10  2015 ..
drwx------   2 darren darren  4096 Nov  1  2015 .ecryptfs
-rw-rw-r--   1 darren darren  1278 Apr  7 15:15 .encfs6.xml
drwx------ 145 darren darren 45056 Apr  7 11:50 .Private
```

If I try to mount the backed up directory to retrieve files, I get no errors from encfs but no files are visible in the mounted directory:

```
darren@hepburn ~ $ encfs -v /mnt/snapshots/hourly.0/hepburn/home/.ecryptfs/darren/ /tmp/backup
VER Root directory: /mnt/snapshots/hourly.0/hepburn/home/.ecryptfs/darren/ [main.cpp:540]
VER Fuse arguments: (daemon) (threaded) (keyCheck) encfs /tmp/backup/ -o use_ino -o default_permissions  [main.cpp:541]
VER found new serialization format [FileUtils.cpp:294]
VER subVersion = 20100713 [FileUtils.cpp:308]
VER checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0) [Interface.cpp:110]
VER allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16 [SSL_Cipher.cpp:333]
VER useStdin: 0 [FileUtils.cpp:1588]
EncFS Password: 
VER checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0) [Interface.cpp:110]
VER allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16 [SSL_Cipher.cpp:333]
VER cipher key size = 52 [FileUtils.cpp:1596]
VER checking if nameio/block(4:0:2) implements nameio/block(4:0) [Interface.cpp:110]

darren@hepburn ~ $ ls -al /tmp/backup/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  4 darren darren  4096 Apr  7 15:15 .
drwxrwxrwt 35 root   root   61440 Apr  7 15:50 ..
```

It's not a password issue, if I use the wrong one I'm told about it:

```
...
EncFS Password: 
VER checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0) [Interface.cpp:110]
VER allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16 [SSL_Cipher.cpp:333]
VER cipher key size = 52 [FileUtils.cpp:1596]
VER checksum mismatch: expected 3670270093, got 4217147638 [SSL_Cipher.cpp:541]
VER on decode of 48 bytes [SSL_Cipher.cpp:543]
Error decoding volume key, password incorrect
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem I'm seeing is that encrypted homes usually use eCryptFS, and not EncFS, therefore it's normal that EncFS won't be able to decrypt any of those files.

I'm also not seeing any of the typically long random filenames of encrypted files in the directory you're trying to decrypt.

If you just copied your home files using rsync / rsnapshot, then you should try the eCryptFS tool `ecryptfs-recover-private` instead (FYI it's a shell script file you can read & even run line-by-line yourself if you wanted).

---

If you are just using EncFS to encrypt a backup of some eCryptFS folders, and not trying to decrypt an eCryptFS folder, then the syslog might have some messages from encfs, or you could try the -f (foreground) option along with -v to see messages in the terminal, and check for new messages when you try reading the decrypted folder & any files inside.

Comment: you're quite right, I realised this not long after posting the question actually and forgot to come back and add a comment. I do use EncFS elsewhere and was of course mixing the 2 up because it was so long since I'd had to decrypt the $HOME dir. https://davison.github.io/2019/04/08/encryption-and-backups.html